# Mutate based on two arguments

Tags: r

Anyone know how to mutate values in a column with arguments both including the value in the given column and a value of another column. For example, mutate all values in `X1` that has `NA` and that has value 0 in `X3`. Thinking there should be a way to include both `IF` and `AND`.

Something like this. This obviously does not work. Trying to mutate in two columns.

```
DF <- DF %>% mutate(X1 = ifelse(is.na(X1)) & X3 = 1), 0, X1),
                                  X2 = ifelse(is.na(X2)) & X3 = 1), 0, X2))
```

Using R.

Answer (score 2):

You may try(I'm confusing with your condition. If there's a mistake, please let me know.)

```
DF <- data.frame(
  X1 = c(1,2,NA,4,NA,5),
  X2 = c(NA,2,3,4,1,NA),
  X3 = c(0,1,0,1,1,0)
)

  X1 X2 X3
1  1 NA  0
2  2  2  1
3 NA  3  0
4  4  4  1
5 NA  1  1
6  5 NA  0

DF %>%
  mutate(X1 = ifelse(is.na(X1) & X3 == 0, 0, X1) ,
              X2 = ifelse(is.na(X2)  & X3 == 0, 0, X2))

  X1 X2 X3
1  1  0  0
2  2  2  1
3  0  3  0
4  4  4  1
5 NA  1  1
6  5  0  0
```

Comment: 'X3' is a dummy variable. So I want to mutate all NAs in 'X1' and 'X2' to 0 if the dummy variable is 0, otherwise it should remain NA. So, if 'X1' = NA and 'X3' (Dummy) = 0 --> then the variable in 'X1' = 0. Thank you! Sorry, the problem was badly described..

Comment: @Cecmel I thought it need to check `X3` against `1`. I edit some code, and I think I may still misunderstand your condition. Please check it out.

Comment: X3 is either 1 or 0. I want to mutate all NA values in X1 and X2 to 0, IF X3 = 0. Tried the code, but the NAs in X1 and X2 (that has X3 = 0) is still NA.

Comment: @Cecmel You mean that `X3` is not column, just a single value? Or in column `X3` it has 0 or 1 in it as I edited the data?

Comment: X3 is a column with values equal to 1 or 0.

Comment: @Cecmel Then is there any problem with my code above now?

Comment: Now its working! Thank you very much!! :D